# Powershell Script to generate site collection administrators, site URL, Site Name,Members in the group named 'owners'

Tags: list, permissions, powershell, site-collection, download

I have a requirement currently to generate all the Sharepoint site in a Web application with the following information:
Site URL
Site Name
Site Collection Administors : ID or name
Members in the group named 'owners'

As such, if anyone has a script or a reference please share it. I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Palani,

```
Get-SPWebApplication "http://server-name:8080"|Get-SPSite -limit ALL|Get-SPWeb -limit ALL|Select-Object Title,Url,AssociatedOwnerGroup
```

This will give you Title, Url and the Associated Owner Group for the site... You can than reference the powershell script:
[PowerShell Script for SP2010 to pull Farm and Site Collections Administrators](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/PowerShell-Script-for-aeba93d8)

Try merging these two and you can get the results, let me know if you are not able to figure out exact!

Comment: @ Arsalan Adam Khatri
Thanks a lot for the reply, however the requirement is something different. I have be asked to generate an excel report with the following fields.
Site URL Site Name Site Collection Administrators Members in the 'owners' group...
if you have a script for that, kindly share it...

Comment: Finally got the scripts referring the below links:

http://santoshksp.wordpress.com/2012/10/19/27/

http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2010/12/sharepoint-powershell-script-to-list.html

Comment: Great, kindly post the complete script as answer and mark it correct.. It may help others!